# How do I use lxml findall() to look for a keyword in elements

Tags: python, lxml, keyword, findall

I have the following RetroPie gamelist.xml that I am trying to return game elements from using lxml's findall(). I want it to return matches that are close to the title I am searching for, or even based on part of the title I am searching for.

```
<gameList>
 <game id="2652" source="ScreenScraper">
          <path>/home/pi/RetroPie/roms/snes/2020 Super Baseball (U).smc</path>
          <name>SUPER BASEBALL 2020</name>
          <desc>* shortened *</desc>
          <image>/home/pi/RetroPie/media/snes/2020 Super Baseball (U)-  image.png</image>
          <marquee/>
          <video>/home/pi/RetroPie/media/snes/2020 Super Baseball (U)-          video.mp4</video>
          <thumbnail/>
          <rating>0.9</rating>
          <releasedate>19930713T000000</releasedate>
          <developer>Pallas</developer>
          <publisher>SNK</publisher>
          <genre>Sports</genre>
          <players>1-2</players>
     </game>
</gameList>
```

So I am looking for something that will return the games that match the title I am searching for, in the example of   "Super Baseball" the above should be returned (the whole game element). Ideas? I have tried xpath and other things, but I lack the ability to make it work as intended.

Something like:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3

 from lxml import etree

 tree = etree.parse("/home/pi/scripts/jscraper2/repackxml/snes/gamelist.xml")
 root = tree.getroot()

 strGame = "Super Baseball 2020"
 for game in root.findall("game/name/"+strGame):
     print(game)
```

Which of course returns nothing. I can go thru games one by one and look for exact matches but that seems slow and I also feel like there must be an easier way to do it:

```
 for game in root:
     strName = ""
     for ele in game:
         if ele.tag == "name":
             strName = str(ele.text)
             if strName.lower() == gameName.lower():
                 # at this point, game would be the element
```

Maybe there is even some regex-fu I could use with the above to look for partial name matches. Anyway, any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Post updated with some more information and the code I've tried to get to work.

Comment: I'd suggest googling for "XPath string contains".

Comment: `//game/name[contains(., "Super")][contains(., "Baseball")][contains(., "2020"])` would handle searching for the three words without caring about their order, f/e. That said, if you want something that's going to be *fast*, I'd suggest using an engine built to do full-text indexing of structured data -- [BaseX](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Indexes#Full-Text_Index) if you want to keep your data in XML, or ElasticSearch if you have a JSON representation, or what-have-you.

Comment: Charles Duffy you are the man! Got what I was looking. I appreciate the help.